AWS NLB self-hosted k8s weird issue
My setup is as below:
Self-hosted k8s (kubespray) running on 5 EC2 instances on AWS. 3 control plane nodes. 2 worker nodes.
Kong ingress controller
private NLB (created by kong deployment)
Private NLB --> Target Group --> has 2 targets (2 worker nodes). NodePort
domain -> aws..com is mapped to NLB DNS name. This corresponds to an ingress on the k8s cluster managed by the Kong ingress controller
Issue
On only the 2 worker nodes, doing a curl to the above domain results in intermittent timeouts. On the 3 control plane nodes, curl works fine 100% of the time without any timeouts. I suspect this is happening because the curl request from the worker node is getting re-routed to itself on the NodePort (via NLB) and is somehow getting dropped somewhere. On the control plane nodes, it is working because the request is not getting routed any of the control plane nodes.
Hope I am able to explain the issue clearly. I have no clue as to why this is happening and how to fix. Any leads/clues will be much appreciated.

Found the cause. Answering it here for anyone who stumbles on the same.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#loopback-timeout
Root cause: When client IP preservation is enabled on target groups, NLB doesn't support NAT loopback i.e. connections time out when source and destination are the same. The connection succeeds only when request is routed through a different target other than the source. If we require client IP for whatever reason in the future, we need to use the Proxy v2 API and X-Forwarded-For request header.
Solution: Disable client IP preservation on NLB Target group by adding the below annotation on ingress controller
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes: "preserve_client_ip.enabled=false"
